# High Power RGB Led control

Tags: led, rgb

We have got a **20W** led ,**RGB** from a good seller in China.

I have a few questions regarding the led (see the attached image)

1. Is there a data sheet to this Leds? something generic ?
2. How can you know where are the RGB pins, and the voltage pins ?
3. I tried to understand how are the control lines are working, and i was thinking that like any other led strip the control lines are only connects the RGB lines to ground, with a high current N-CHANNEL FET .

The seller told me this :

```
R:14-17V       G:21-24V         B:21-24V
 R：1150mA-1400mA   G：800-950mA  B：800-950mA
```

Is it means that the control lines are with these voltages ??

Please see the attached image.
thanks very much.[image]

Comment: (1) and (2) - Ask the "good seller". He will respond if he is good.

Comment: Have you bodered to read my question? Cynics is not good for your health. The seller did provide answer which seems not reasonable to me and since leds are usually the same for each package ,i am asking here the good people for help.

Comment: @Curnelious your question doesn't say "I asked the seller didn't reply"

Comment: These are probably just naked LEDs in series.  You could find the pins by trial and error with a lab power supply (voltage somewhat higher than the ones specified and a low current limit of a few mA should do).  Note you also need quite a bit of cooling to run it at full power.

Comment: "seller did provide answer which seems not reasonable to me" OK, just to help us out, what (exactly, not YOUR version of it) did the seller say, and why doesn't that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just poke around with a 30V power supply with a 1K resistor in series, as Starblue suggests and you'll quickly figure it out (I suggest the resistor because the output capacitor of even a current-limited power supply could damage the LEDs conceivably)

Probably 3 strings of series or series/parallel with a common. Whether it's common anode or cathode is unknown.

Chances are the top strip in your photo is the **common**, and the bottom left is **red** and the other two are **green** and **blue** (maybe not that order for green and blue).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLKccp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You need to limit the operating current into the LEDs to less than the smaller of the rated current and the maximum allowed by the power dissipation. As in the comments if you power this up at anywhere near the claimed 20W input power it will see perhaps 18W of heating and will expire in short order.